# policy contains an invalid JSON POLICY

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am getting this error message  "Policy containes an invalid JSON policy"when i run terraform apply but when i do terraform validate policy is validated.I dont know what am doing wrongly.please help.

policy = <<EOF

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}"]
        },
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":[
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}/*"]
        },
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":[
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:kms:${var.region}:${var.aws_account_id}:key/${var.key_id}"
        }
    ]
}
```

}
EOF

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given much detail but I just bumped into this myself so this answer makes some assumptions.

There is an [issue with aws_iam_role_policy](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3970#issuecomment-389309609) noted in the aws terraform provider which I can't word any better so here's the content:

> Most probably it's because the policy contains leading spaces.
>
> For resource "aws_iam_role" assume_role_policy (and leading spaces in the JSON), terraform shows an error message that the policy cannot contain leading spaces.
> However, for resource "aws_iam_role_policy" (and leading spaces in the JSON), terraform simply says that policy contains an invalid JSON policy.
>
> I think that the error message given by terraform in this case should be more specific.

Remove any leading spaces in your JSON.

```
  policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect":"Allow",
"Action":["s3:ListBucket"],
"Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}"]
},
{
"Effect":"Allow",
"Action":[
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:GetObjectVersion"
],
"Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}/*"]
},
{
"Effect":"Allow",
"Action":[
"kms:Decrypt"
],
"Resource":"arn:aws:kms:${var.region}:${var.aws_account_id}:key/${var.key_id}"
}
]
}
  EOF
```

Or use the indented heredoc form which allows leading space

```
  policy = <<-EOF
{
  "indented":"true",
}
EOF
```

Or stop writing policies etc out in their raw form and use the [Terraform policy document data sources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) to create your definitions and attach them using policy resources e.g.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "alb_pub_log_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.alb_pub_log_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.alb_pub_log_bucket.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "alb_pub_log_bucket" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["s3:PutObject"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.alb_pub_log_bucket}",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.alb_pub_log_bucket}/*"
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_elb_service_account.public.id}:root"]
    }
  }
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["s3:PutObject"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.alb_pub_log_bucket}",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.alb_pub_log_bucket}/*"
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"
      values   = ["bucket-owner-full-control"]
    }
  }
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["s3:GetBucketAcl"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::${var.alb_pub_log_bucket}"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"]
    }

  }

}
```

Which will give you earlier visibility of any policy errors as the data source is computed during validate/plan etc.

Comment: "Remove any leading spaces in your JSON." looks very ugly in code but it did solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ashrafminhaj Agreed it's ugly so if you can't use the preferred Terraform document resources just tweak your heredoc from `<<EOF` to `<<-EOF`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your final `Resource` is not wrapped in a bracket `[]`...

Comment: This is perfectly valid

Answer (score 0):

Change to `jsonencode` according to terraform:

***Terraform's `jsonencode` function converts a Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.***

Reference:
[aws_iam_role_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy.html)